# aiogram. Remove executor messages from console

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, polling, executor, aiogram

Using python3 aiogram library for a telegram bot. Is there a way to remove the messages from console generated by the executor? messages like `Goodbye!` or `Updates were skipped successfully.` if you start polling using skip_updates=True

My bot has on the start part this:

```
# Start the bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start(dp, notify_message())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

And I'm receiving that annoying messages in console. Is there a parameter to turn them off? I can't find anything on aiogram docs. If there is not an option for this, any python3 /dev/null related dirty trick?